# how to run a perl program in browser using Mojolicious framework

Tags: apache, perl, browser, mojolicious

How can I run a Perl program in a web browser using the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) framework?

I googled for CGI, and some sources say CGI is outdated and suggested trying the Mojolicious framework.

Can anyone suggest how to run a Perl program in a browser using the Mojoliciousframework?

Comment: Are you asking how to write web applications in Perl? If so, that's far too broad (and thus off-topic) and you should just read the mojolious tutorial. Are you asking how to port an existing Perl program to a web application? That is just as broad and also impossible to answer without seeing the existing code. Are you asking how to run a Perl program from another Perl program? That depends on what input and output you need to provide to / get from the program you are trying to control programatically so you'd need to provide more information before it could be answered.

Comment: http://mojolicio.us/ has example code and extensive documentation. What part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Perl program not running in browser. It running in server and client load page which have url to this server).

For beginners:

mojo generate app MyApp

```
alex@Vena:~/Test $ mojo generate app MyApp
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/script
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/script/my_app
  [chmod] my_app/script/my_app 744
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/lib
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/lib/MyApp.pm
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/lib/MyApp
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/lib/MyApp/Example.pm
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/t
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/t/basic.t
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/log
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/public
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/public/index.html
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/templates/layouts
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/templates/layouts/default.html.ep
  [mkdir] /home/alex/Test/my_app/templates/example
  [write] /home/alex/Test/my_app/templates/example/welcome.html.ep
alex@Vena:~/Test $ cd my_app/
alex@Vena:~/Test/my_app $ ls
lib  log  public  script  t  templates
alex@Vena:~/Test/my_app $ morbo script/my_app 
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000.
```

Now you can load page in browser using url `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

To run your app in production use `hypnotoad` instead `morbo`